how to maintain media's selection order?
i'm trying to render selected images and videos based on the exact order they are selected. but no matter what i try the images and video render based on recently added to gallery it seems like.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default function App() {
  const [mediaFiles, setMediaFiles] = useState([]);

  const pickMedia = async () => {
    try {
      const results = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
        multiple: true,
        mediaType: 'any',
      });

      let mediaDetails = [];
      
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        const asset = results[String(i)];
        const mediaItem = {
          id: String(i),
          contentType: asset.mime,
          fileSize: asset.size,
          filePath: asset.path,
          type: asset.mime,
        };
        mediaDetails.push(mediaItem);
      }

      setMediaFiles(mediaDetails);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error picking media:', error);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.mediaContainer}>
      {item.type.startsWith('image') ? (
        <Image source={{ uri: item.filePath }} style={styles.image} />
      ) : (
        <Video
          source={{ uri: item.filePath }}
          style={styles.video}
          controls
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick media from gallery" onPress={pickMedia} />
      {mediaFiles.length === 0 ? (
        <Text>No media selected</Text>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={mediaFiles}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          numColumns={2}
          contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10 }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mediaContainer: {
    margin: 5,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  video: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});


i want the order i select to be the order the images and videos are rendered in. Currently i downloaded 2 images and 1 video to my simulator. No matter what i try the media is always rendered with the video first then the middle image and the  first image downloaded. so it seems its maintaining the order they were downloaded (most recent) not selected.
